# SQL Query to MySQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

Well, I was watching a video tutorial on youtube about making a program with c# and using a database. The guy was using SQL commands while I was using MySQL through phpmyadmin (XAMPP is love).

I've managed to keep going until I reached one part where the guy was creating stored procedures and input this code:

```
create procedure datosfactura @NumFac int
as
select
F.*, D.PrecioVen, D.CanVe, C.Nom_cli, A.Nom_pro, D.PrecioVen * D.CanVe as importe
from
Facturas F inner join Detalles D on F.NunFac = D.NumFac
inner join Articula A on D.CodPro = A.id_pro
inner join Cliente C on F.CodCli = C.id_clientes
where F.NumFac = @NumFac
```

I racket my brain and tried different ways but I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

As it is, if I make a new MySQL command inputting that query it returns that there's an error in the first line.

What is the right way to convert this SQL query into MySQL? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Isn't that SQL Server code?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html?

Comment: I realized I put "A.Nom-pro" instead "A.Nom_pro" (notice the _) i changed that but the problem still persists.

jarlh thank you for the documentation but the more I read it the more confussing it gets haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
delimiter //
create procedure datosfactura(NumFac int)
begin
    select F.*, 
           D.PrecioVen, 
           D.CanVe, 
           C.Nom_cli, 
           A.Nom_pro, 
           D.PrecioVen * D.CanVe as importe
    from Facturas F 
    inner join Detalles D on F.NunFac = D.NumFac
    inner join Articula A on D.CodPro = A.id_pro
    inner join Cliente C on F.CodCli = C.id_clientes
    where F.NumFac = NumFac;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Useful articles:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Thank you! This one did work. But, if I may ask, why isnt it the '@' in there? I thought MySQL supported that.

Comment: @Revers3 This is first time I see something like that, apparently, procedure/function parameters are special in MySQL. Variables are defined usually with `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (i dont have access to mysql now)

```
delimiter $$
create function datosfactura(IN NumFac int)
BEGIN
select
F.*, D.PrecioVen, D.CanVe, C.Nom_cli, A.Nom_pro, D.PrecioVen * D.CanVe as 
importe
from
Facturas F inner join Detalles D on F.NunFac = D.NumFac
inner join Articula A on D.CodPro = A.id_pro
inner join Cliente C on F.CodCli = C.id_clientes
where F.NumFac = NumFac
end $$
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but I tested it and it didnt work. Also, it seems using '$' isnt a good idea, because phpmyadmin kept throwing errors.